# How to optimize this linq to objects query?

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

I'm matching some in memory lists entities with a .contains (subselect) query to filter out old from new users.

Checking for performance problems i saw this:

[image]

The oldList mostly has around 1000 users in them, while the new list varies from 100 to 500. Is there a way to optimize this query?

Comment: 1 for 12 on accepted answers. Might want to improve upon that. Also, what add-on is giving you that metric?

Comment: I used the performance profiler of vs2010, it comes with the ultimate version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely - build a set instead of checking a list each time:

```
// Change string to whatever the type of UserID is.
var oldUserSet = new HashSet<string>(oldList.Select(o => o.UserID));
var newUsers = NewList.Where(n => !oldUserSet.Contains(n.UserID))
                      .ToList();
```

The containment check on a `HashSet` should be O(1) assuming few hash collisions, instead of the O(N) of checking each against the whole sequence (for each new user).

Answer (score 2):

You could make a `HashSet<T>` of your user IDs in advance.  This will cause the `Contains` to become an O(1) operation:

```
var oldSet = new HashSet<int>(oldList.Select(o => o.UserID));
var newUsers = NewList.Where(n => !oldSet.Contains(n.UserID)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

While those `HashSet<T>` answers are straightforward and simple, some may prefer a linq-centric solution.

LinqToObjects implements join and GroupJoin with a HashSet.  Just use one of those - this example uses GroupJoin:

```
List<User> newUsers =
  (
    from n in NewList
    join o in oldList on n.UserId equals o.UserId into oldGroup
    where !oldGroup.Any()
    select n
  ).ToList()
```